# Can't seal Vault with non-root token

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Can't seal Vault, neither on CLI or with HTTP API, citing permission problems, using a token from userpass with a policy with permissions on `sys/seal`. However, by generating a root token it can seal normally.

[The documentation at the official site](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/seal) mentions:

> This endpoint seals the Vault. In HA mode, only an active node can be sealed. Standby nodes should be restarted to get the same effect. **Requires a token with root policy or sudo capability on the path**.

### Policy

```
path "sys/seal"
{
    capabilities = ["create", "sudo"]
}
```

### Error message

```
Error sealing: Error making API request.

URL: PUT <HOST>/v1/sys/seal
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"update"` capability was required.

```
path "sys/seal"
{
    capabilities = ["create", "update", "sudo" ]
}
```